# How do I stop evaluation when looking up a column value?

Tags: r, dataframe

This must be simple but I can't think of the correct way to do it. I have the following data frame:

```
legend = data.frame(
           name = c("A - B","A", "A + B"), 
           color = rainbow(3), 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am trying to get the color that corresponds to "A - B" so I do:

```
color.for.a.minus.b <- legend[legend$name == "A - B"]$color[1]
```

And I get an error `undefined columns defined` probably because it is actually thinking I want to evaluate "A - B" which I don't want to do. I just want to find the color that corresponds to that value.

Comment: Try putting the pieces together piece by piece.  Run `legend$name == "A - B"` and see if it gives what you expect. Run `legend[legend$name == "A - B"]` and see if it gives what you expect... and so on until you identify where your expectations don't match reality.

Comment: Try `legend$color[legend$name == "A - B"]` or even `legend[legend$name == "A - B", "color"]`.

Comment: @mickey - that worked! How is your way different than mine?

Comment: It's the way data.frames handle indexing the columns. e.g. `legend[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]` will try to get the first and third columns. You don't have a third column, hence the error. My first example gets the `color` column as a vector and is indexed more intuitively (e.g. get the first element). The second example uses more of a `[row, column]` index, similar to how you'd index a matrix.

Comment: feel free to add this as an answer